# Join a model with itself in Yii causes non-object error

Tags: yii, yii-relations

I have a model with these fields :

```
id , name , parent_id
```

I store a hirechical structure in this table.

somw example records are:

```
1 - fruits - 0
2 - foods -  0
3 - colors - 0
4 - apple -  1
5 - red -    3   
6 - meat-    2
```

In the gridview of manage(admin) page I want to show the parent name instead of its id.
so I define this relation in the model (stuff).

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(
     'parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'stuff', 'parent_id'),
  );
}
```

and in view :

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'mygrid',
   'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
   'filter'=>$model,
   'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
            array(
                    'name' => 'parent name',
                    'value' => '$data->parent->name'
          ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
    ),
     )); 

?>
```

But I get 'Trying to get property of non-object' error on admin page. It seems it is because of the root patents which their parent_id is '0' and there is no record with id=0 .

How can I deal with this problem?

Thanks you in advanced.

Comment: can u post your stuff model ?? i.e fields in your stuff table ?

Comment: I have mentioned stuff model fields at the top of the question.

Comment: Can u create another table called As parent with parent_id and parentname fields ?

Comment: no all the records should be in the same table because each one can have some children.

Comment: but there is no record with id=0 ? Put it blank and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a check to the value expression

```
array(
    'name'=>'parent.name',
    'value'=>'($data->parent_id)?data->parent->name:""'
)
```

**EDIT**

For best practice you should leave `parent_id` blank instead of putting in a zero. If not every single time you want to access the parent using `$model->parent` you would have to perform the above check. Also for the grid `parent.name` could have been used instead of the above.

```
'name',
'parent.name',
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
),
```

Comment: I did , but it seems the problem is because of relation. because the error is shown in view page too.